# Python, Datetime Objects

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I'm still learning how to code in Python, so an answer that's more beginner-friendly, rather efficient would be much appreciated. 
So I have written a block of code that retrieves the creation date of the files, and I appended it to a list as such:

```
path = r'C:\\...'
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx")
dates = []
for filename in all_files:
    mod_date = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(filename)).strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
    dates.append(mod_date)
    dates.sort()
dates
```

The output is as such:

```
['04-24-2020',
 '04-27-2020',
 '04-28-2020',
 '04-29-2020',
 '04-30-2020',
 '05-01-2020',
 '05-04-2020',
 '05-05-2020',
 '05-06-2020',
 '05-07-2020',
 '05-08-2020',
 '05-11-2020',
 '05-12-2020',
 '05-13-2020',
 '05-14-2020',
 '05-15-2020',
 '05-18-2020',
 '05-19-2020',
 '05-20-2020',
 '05-21-2020']
​
```

I wanted to make a loop that would detect when the month changes, but I wanted it in a way where I would **not** just only read the month as such:

```
mod_date = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(filename)).strftime('%m')
```

I still need the **full** date in order for me to run some other code with it at the same time. 
I want it to kind of look like:

```
for i in range(0, len(dates)):
    if (month != month[i]): <<< something along the lines of this
       print("hello")
```

A hint on how I would get the if statement going would be appreciated. Or if this is not possibly please tell me on how I should *approach* this. Sorry this is really long, but the problem I hope should be a small fix. **Note: it should still work if there is a discontinuity in dates i.e. if the month jumps from January to March instead of looking for February.**

Comment: Why did you convert the datetimes to strings? you could compare my_dates[i].month > my_dates[i-1].month, while still having the whole datetime object to do whatever you want with it later?

Comment: I agree with Paul, you should have just kept the date objects and not converted them into string.

Comment: Umm I didn't convert my datetimes into strings. That's just how the output looks I believe.

Comment: I get what you meant now. I didn't look at the code long enough.

Comment: Ah I see. I apologize that I didn't understand it the first time. I wanted to see what the date actually was rather than a bunch of numbers as the outputs, which was why I made it into a "MM-DD-YYYY"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you told that you'd want to have the full date, rather than just the month, you could do something as follows: (considering `date_list` the output you provided for the .xlsx file)

```py
def check_month(date_list):
    for date_string in date_list:
        # you have the date for later use
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, '%m-%d-%Y')
        try:
            if (date.month, date.year) != (prev_date.month, prev_date.year):
                print(f'changed at {date}')
        except NameError:
            pass
        prev_date = date

check_month(date_list)
# outputs: changed at 2020-05-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: Hmm it ran the first time properly, but if I rerun it without changing anything besides "date_list" to dates. I get this: changed at 2020-04-24 00:00:00
changed at 2020-05-01 00:00:00

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. Sorry I'm still new to all of this.

Comment: No problem, we have all been there. That happened because variables defined into a for loop are put in the namespace of the parent scope that the for loop is within.

Comment: For completeness, you should also check whether the year changed, otherwise a jump from January of one year and January of the next year won't be detected.

Comment: @sabik Good point! I didn't have that in mind. Updating the answer to consider that possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood correctly what you want, but for a loop you could use something like:

```
for i in range(len(dates) - 1):
    if dates[i][:2] != dates[i + 1][:2]:
        print("ok")
```

Comment: I think this would give me an IndexError since the if statement looks forward and can't iterate at the last loop. But I think I could make it look at the previous iteration. Thank you for that tip!

Comment: It doesn't as it iterates until Len - 1.

Comment: For completeness, you should also check whether the year changed, otherwise a jump from January of one year and January of the next year won't be detected.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, especially useful if you need to do some setup or cleanup for each month, would be to use the [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function.

(As others have suggested, don't do the `.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')` until the end when you're ready to output the data.)

```
for filename in all_files:
    mod_date = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(filename))
    dates.append(mod_date)

dates.sort()
grouped_dates = itertools.groupby(dates, lambda date: (date.year, date.month))

for (year, month), date_group in grouped_dates:
    print("Starting month %s-%s" % (month, year))
    for date in date_group:
        print("Processing %s" % date.strftime('%m-%d-%Y'))
    print("Finished month %s-%s" % (month, year))
```